# Which are the applications, using the java environment

Tags: java

This might be a basic question, but I searched for it before posting it.

I'm an SAP Guy. 
Earlier SAP used to rely on Vendor JVM: SunJDK.
Now it has developed its own, called SAP JVM.

My question is:
On a Unix OS, how do I know how many applications are using the JAVA_HOME environment?
-OR-
How do I know on Unix which applications are using the java environments?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? It's an environment variable, any program can (but doesn't necessarily) use it.

Comment: I can easily know , SAP using SAP JVM ,But I am looking here how do i know which other applications(apart from SAP) , which are installed on the same OS , using the java env.

Comment: Maybe you want to use some Unix tools such as `top` and see which applications are running a `java` process...

Answer (score 5):

So a relatively naive way of doing this would be to run:

```
ps -elf | grep java
```

this will list out all the current processes that were started using java.

Comment: Hi Guys, i found ,That is , we have files called j2eeenv.csh and j2eeenv.sh , in which we maintain the java home environments , but still my quest for finding how many java applications running on , an , Unix host , still searching
I did try ps - ef | grep java , but no results for this.
Can any one give a different approach here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi all , any other feedbacks or suggests for this ?

Comment: @SidharthMellam what was the output?

Comment: Another way to look at the current java process's is to run the command "jvisualvm"